# Selenium returns empty text instead of the actual value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the value inside of an iframe. Here is the part I got stuck at

```
<input tabindex="20" class="dxeEditArea dxeEditAreaSys" name="txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU" value="1009" maxlength="8" id="txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU_I" onchange="ASPx.EValueChanged('txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU')" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU')" type="text" style="text-align:Left;" autocomplete="off">
```

I tried using but no luck so far.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU_I").get_attribute("innerText"))
driver.find_element_by_id("txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU_I").get_attribute("value"))
```

It only returns me empty string.

Also here is the full xpath :

```
/html/body/form/div[4]/fieldset/div[4]/table[14]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input
```

**Edit2:**

I discovered that if I inspect the page I can see the value, but if I get the value from the innerHtml with the code like this

```
print(driver.find_element_by_id("txt_MAHALLE").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

It does not exist as a value.

Comment: what is the name of the iframe? can you share the url?

Comment: Hey, i cannot share the url. I am accessing it through a teamviewer and it is only enabled on local computers. The name of the i frame is "MIframe1". I think since the returned texts are disable i am not able to retrieve them.  @Isma

Comment: Is the id "txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU_I" you are using is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I had already switched to iframe before asking the question, otherwise i would not be able to send input to the page and the page would not return me results. I could not share the codes but the workflow was like, click some links to access to an iframe and send inputs to a box inside of an iframe and then click a button to get results and copy results.

I was able to solve my problem by first putting a wait by `time.sleep(10)` then assigning a wait untill all the elements in the page are visible by using

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 150).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "the element"))).
```

After that i accessed all elements by using

`driver.find_element_by_id("the element").get_attribute("value")`

Answer (score 0):

try with explicit wait :- you need to switch to iframe like below and if ID `txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU_I` is unique the you can get `value` attribute like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "MIframe1")))
print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "txt_CADDE_SOKAK_KODU_I"))).get_attribute('value'))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```